# Slow performance running VM Player image (virtual machine) on USB3.0 external drive

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, vmware-player, usb-3

I have a virtual image I'm trying to run over USB3.0 on an external drive using VM Player. The performance is very slow and I cant seem to find the culprit. I've ran some benchmarking tools and my UP speed is 35 - 40 mbps and down speed is 85 - 90 mbps. I'm thinking this is sufficient to run the player.

I've searched and there is a posting on VM's player about making a change to the header file to increase performance, but its a very old posting and doesn't apply to the latest players. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1620

I'm sure there are others out there running images on USB3, right? Anyone have problems with VM player?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean read/write when you say up/down. Your write speed should be similar and not half of your read speed with a HDD, so you have a problem there.

If you're using a flash drive (memory stick) the speed difference is normal, but performance on small read and write is very bad (except on some expensive flash drives that are using SSD controllers) so the performance you get is normal.

Comment: Im curious if anyone out there is successfully using VM player over USB? My external drive is not SSD but from what I've searched, my transfer rates are about norm for USB, so SSD may not help me.

Comment: So is it a hard drive or not? If yes your read and write speeds should be about the same. What do the seek times look like when testing with HDTune or something similar?